# Gold-standard Uno + ReactiveUI starter project on NET 7.0 that works

Tags: reactiveui, .net-7.0, uno-platform

This is day 2 and I am trying to get a working starter app with Reactive UI and the Uno platform.

I have been struggling with myriads of compatibility issues, runtime issues, and installation issues. I am at the point of utter desperation just to get something working that runs the starter "Hello World" app on all Uno supporting platforms - iOS, Android, Windows, Mac, Linux and WebAssembly.

The main and probably only documentation that I've found is the [Getting started with Uno Platform and ReactiveUI](https://platform.uno/blog/getting-started-with-uno-platform-and-reactiveui/) page. That's the page I started following upfront, but faced the first issue as the documentation is outdated. Instead of referencing the `ReactiveUI.UnoUI` I should have referenced  `ReactiveUI.Uno.WinUI` as my solution has the newer Uno version with WinUI support. It took at least several hours to figure that out.

Further, the second source is the [ReactiveUI.Samples](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples). But the sample inside is outdated. And it doesn't follow the steps described in the first link above - such as setting up `IHost` and dependency injection.

Now, I finally was able to launch all of the applications, except for Web Assembly. However, it was a very unpleasant experience to even reach this point. Thus, I would really be happy if there was one source of truth that has up-to-date documentation of bootstrapping Reactive UI Uno application on NET 7.0 which works without having to deal with so many incompatibilities and discrepancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Uno Platform and ReactiveUI support GitHub issues and GitHub discussions.
Those allow you to directly ask for help and even request documentation or samples updates.

### GitHub Issues

- https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/new/choose
- https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/new/choose

### GitHub Discussions

- https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/discussions
- https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/discussions